# Send and Receive Object of a Class in MPI - JAVA

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, mpi

I'm trying to send and receive an object of a Java class using MPI.

I'm serializing the object (could be an error there)
Here's my code:

```
ObjectProva obj = new ObjectProva(1,"test");

if (rank == 0) {
  String serialized = "";
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
  oos.writeObject(obj);
  oos.flush();
  serialized = baos.toString();
  char [] message_char = serialized.toCharArray() ;
  MPI.COMM_WORLD.send(message_char, message_char.length, MPI.CHAR, 1, 99) ;
}
else {
  ObjectProva ob = null;
  char [] messagetorecv = new char [115];
  MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(messagetorecv, 115, MPI.CHAR, MPI.ANY_SOURCE, 99);
  byte b[] = new String(messagetorecv).getBytes();
  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
  ob = (ObjectProva) ois.readObject();              //This is null
}
```

The last object results to be null. I think it's a deserialization problem, however I'm not even sure about the `MPI.recv` part.

Comment: try sending the serialized message size first, and allocate `messagetorecv` with the exact size.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I tried also but the object result to be null.
The rest of the code is ok in your opinion?
Thanks

Comment: I have not done these things for 20+ years, but so fat, `baos.toString()` looks suspicious to me. Try sending/receiving an array of `MPI.BYTE` instead. If it does not work, first try serialize/deserialize without MPI.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was exactly like you said. Soon I will post the full working code.